# Getting files of certain extension using PathMatcher

Tags: java, file-extension

I'd like to get all *.pdf files from a directory (and not also with its subdirectories). I use `FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher( "glob:**.pdf")`, but it works recursively.

**EDIT**

I've already tried `FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher( "glob:*.pdf")` but this give me no files (but there are *.pdf files in a given directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> `*.java` Matches a path that represents a file name ending in .java

So the path matcher for `glob:*.java` will only return true for actual file names (e.g. `x.pdf`), which are returned by [Path.getFileName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) for example.

A possible solution to your problem of iterating PDF files in a directory without subdirectories may be limitting the depth of file tree traversal instead of changing the behaviour of the matcher.

```
Path start = Paths.get("C:/Users/maxim/Desktop/test/");
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.pdf");
Files.walk(start, 1)
    .filter(matcher::matches)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This was it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using `glob patterns`.

Use `FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher( "glob:*.pdf")` instead of `FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher( "glob:**.pdf")`.

Following is an extract from [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)):

> The following rules are used to interpret glob patterns:
>
> - The * character matches zero or more characters of a name component **without crossing directory boundaries**.
> - The ** characters matches zero or more characters **crossing directory boundaries**.

Comment: I have already done this. It gives me no files while there are *.pdf files in my directory.